# VBA Excel : Populate TextBox with specific string of text when Option Button is selected

Tags: excel, textbox, radio-button, vba

I developed a Form in Excel (2016) and I am trying (with VBA) to configure its behavior so that if the user selects a particular option button, two additional things happen:

1. A checkbox further down on the form is automatically checked.
2. A text box further down on the form automatically displays a set string of text.

More specifically, if the user selects *OptionButtonABC*, then ...

1. *CheckBoxNone* should become checked
2. *TextBoxCompanyName* (which does not display any text by default) should now display the string: 'ABC'.

I initially created a subroutine that just targeted condition 1, and everything worked fine. However, when I try to integrate the code required to handle condition 2, things start to unravel.

Below, you will see the code in its most current state. I have a Private Sub that initiates upon the Click event and then immediately defines a variable as a string. I then set up an if/then statement that specifies what should happen IF *OptionButtonABC* is true. Namely, *CheckBoxNone* should be selected (this works fine) AND *TextBoxCompanyName* should now display the string 'ABC'.

```
Private Sub OptionButtonABC_Click()
Dim Variable_ABC As String
Variable_ABC = ABC
If Me.OptionButtonABC.Value = True Then
Me.CheckBoxNone = True And Me.TextBoxCompanyName.Text = Variable_ABC
End If
End Sub
```

The desired behavior should (theoretically) be pretty easy to achieve, but my experience with VBA is still pretty limited, so I am reaching out to the community for a bit of advice. As I mentioned above, the code above works for the first condition. However, I am still unable to get the string of text ('ABC') to show up in the text box.

Thanks in advance for any advice you may offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub OptionButtonABC_Click()
Dim Variable_ABC As String
Variable_ABC = "ABC" 'String Values uses double quotes
If Me.OptionButtonABC.Value = True Then
  Me.CheckBoxNone = True
  Me.TextBoxCompanyName.Text = Variable_ABC
End If
End Sub
```

The operator AND must be used only in the IF statement comparison, not in what you want to do.